# Papers of real experiments measuring momentum of individual particles?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, experimental-physics, momentum, measurements, experimental-technique

I am trying to understand the different methods that have been used to measure the momentum of individual particles. I have been able to find a few methods (with corresponding papers describing the method) and linked them below, but I would like to educate myself on more that I might not know!

Some examples of momentum measurement methods I know of are:

- [This paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0168583X95001506) describes an experiment using a technique called recoil ion momentum spectroscopy, in which a helium atom collides with some larger ion, ionizing the helium $He \to He^+ + e^-$. The helium nucleus and electron then fly through a magnetic field, and land on a screen. From the position on the screen and the time between collision and arrival, the momentum of the particle can be inferred.
- [This paper](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.13312) describes the first-ever measurement of the momentum distribution $|\langle p | \psi \rangle |^2$. To measure the momentum, a particle flies through essentially a maze with just the right curvature so that only the trajectory of an electron of a particular momentum would make it through. Inside the "maze" is a field which can be adjusted so that the device becomes sensitive to different momenta.
- Another method is the one used by ATLAS at the LHC using pixel detectors, which measure many positions of a charged particle in a magnetic field and then infer the momentum from the radius of the circle along which the particle moves. I don't have a good reference paper for this (If anyone does that would be great)

For my purposes I do not mind if the momentum is measured just as an intermediate step e.g. to then infer the scattering cross section.

Comment: This seems like an extremely general question, with literally dozens of candidates... is there some underlying thing you're looking for?

Comment: I am trying to understand whether all momentum measurement techniques can also be modeled as position measurements. So far all of the techniques I have seen fit this mold, but I only have been able to find a limited range of techniques. It is true that there may be many different techniques I don't know, or maybe only a small number.

To make the question more specific, I will make it clear that I am focused on measurement techniques, rather than multiple papers for the same technique. I think there won't be that many possible answers then.

Comment: And with particle you mean elementary particle? I measure momentum of my mum-particles with a camera and microscope...

Comment: It seems to me that because Lagrangians are local in position (and not in momentum, energy, or whatever else), you could argue that _all_ measurements of _anything_ are really position measurements. (To be extra pedantic, you could say that the details don't even matter: once you look at any detector's readout screen, you're measuring the positions of photons coming from it with your eyes.) But this isn't a useful way of speaking; it would either confuse or annoy experimentalists.

Comment: I do mean elementary or at least small enough that quantum mechanics should apply. Individual atoms or small molecules would be interesting as well.

Comment: @knzhou Yes that's true you could call anything a position measurement by virtue of reading the positions of the detector particles. But I'm looking for whether the experiments can be modeled as a position measurement on the particle being measured itself. While I think it is probably true, I feel the need to have a more comprehensive overview of known experimental methods first. As for lagrangians, I'm not sure how to use that to prove that one cannot measure momentum by some means that cannot be modeled as a position measurement on the measured particle itself.

Comment: Plenty of energy detectors that aren’t particularly position sensitive…

Comment: @JonCuster Do you have an example? Even just one or two examples would be very helpful.

Comment: Sodium iodide crystals for gamma detection - you can get ones 4x4x16 inches or bigger. Gamma gets absorbed somewhere in it, but you detect the pulse of visible photons to get the energy. Not position sensitive other than ‘somewhere inside’.

Comment: @JonCuster Do you know of a reference which explains the method in detail?

Comment: Multiple companies make NaI gamma detectors. Ortec (say https://www.ortec-online.com/products/radiation-detectors/scintillation-detectors/scintillation-detector-types/905-series) is one. No affiliation, but they are well known in nuclear physics measurement.

Comment: This is great, thank you, will be reading this through.

Comment: @JonCuster This is interesting, if I have understood correctly, in a scintillation detector the energy measurement boils down to a measurement of particle number, namely it is measured by how many visible light photons were emitted after the original pulse collides with the scintillator. Since this was very useful, I can't help myself but to ask, do you have another example of a different type of detector, besides a scintillator, which is used to measure energy or momentum?

Comment: Or else, if you had a reference where I could generally read about various detection techniques I would be forever grateful!

Comment: A surface barrier detector (also Ortec, https://www.ortec-online.com/products/radiation-detectors/silicon-charged-particle-radiation-detectors) is similar, converting charged particle energy to a current pulse.

Comment: And, related to your third bullet, cloud chamber photographs are a classic example to getting $q/m$ for charged particles.

Comment: @JonCuster Thank you :) This has all been really helpful. Another idea I had was to browse the tag 'particle-detectors', which has given me a few more names of detectors.